# Randomly shuffling a column in a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list (called final_list) of pandas DataFrames (3 of them), each with 3 columns. A single dataframe looks like this

```
x   y   T/F
2   0   False
2   1   False
3   2   False
5   3   True
6   4   False
6   5   False
6   6   False
4   7   False
2   8   False
2   9   True
3   10  True
```

I thought I would use random.shuffle to loop through the list and randomize the 'T/F' column like this

```
index = 0
while counter < len(final_list):
    random.shuffle(final_list[counter]['T/F'])
    counter += 1
```

My goal is to have the 'T/F' column in each DataFrame be shuffled around randomly, which means it should be different in each DataFrame, however after running the code the 'T/F' column in each DataFrame is different than the original, but they all are identical to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:
Taking the below as input:

```
final_list=[df,df,df]

list_dfs=[i.assign(**{'T/F':np.random.choice(i['T/F'],len(i))}) for i in final_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for df in final_list:
    d['T/F'] = d['T/F'].sample(frac=1).values
    x   y    T/F
0   2   0  False
1   2   1   True
2   3   2  False
3   5   3   True
4   6   4   True
5   6   5  False
6   6   6  False
7   4   7  False
8   2   8  False
9   2   9  False
10  3  10  False
```